# It's too easy to lose custom bounty-request text

Tags: bug, bounty, user-interface, user-experience

I was typing up a bounty request, and I wanted to include some text from the question I was bountying, but when I clicked elsewhere in the window to select that text, the bounty popup window disappeared, evidently lost forever, and I had to start over.  I seem to have utterly lost, without warning, the (somewhat elaborate) custom bounty request I had begun to type.

Comment: This also happens to any dialog with input text, like the custom comment flag, custom mod flag, custom close reason, etc...